# App rejected due to 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App (World Pay)

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, app-store-connect

I am using world pay for subscription on user in my app and two times my app is rejected can you guys tell me what to do next?

as in whole application whether it is android or web or ios we are using only world pay. So what will be a best solution?

Do I need to integrate in app purchase api or any solution apart from this?

Comment: Generally, you should know what to do by thoroughly reading the reviewer's comments. If you don't understand the directions, post them here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Apple's IAP or handle purchases outside the apple ecosystem

Comment: You are bound to IAP only when you are selling digital products

Answer (score 0):

you can use web view for payment , instead of sdk , world pay sdk will not be approved from apple App Store .

My opinion is to navigate to web view and as your team is using world pay for web you can do like that on web view.

Comment: You can’t use a web view in the app or link to your web site from the app for payment; your app will be rejected if you do